# how to reference to a file in an other solution while unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

i got this line of code:

```
string certfile = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(appConfig.ClientCertificatePfx);
```

as you can see it opens a file. while unit testing i obviously not access it because it's in a different project. My project mentor tells me the cleanest/nicest solution would be to make a refernce to this file in the test project, i just can't seem to figure out how (or what he exactly means- a file that references it or lines of code maybe?).

i am an intern, so this is my "challenge" to find an answer for myself.

Comment: Your mentor is wrong. The cleanest solution is to mock the dependancy using a mocking framework like Moq

Comment: you are probably right, but he is not a great fan of slapping frameworks on everything

Comment: Regardless of mocking framework you have to refactor that code to remove tight coupling to `HostingEnvironment` which is very difficult to test. You should abstract the access to that class and functionality so that it can be more testable and allow for better mocking, be it via mocking your own implementation or using a mocking framework. your class should depend on abstractions and not on concretions.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project => Add, Existing item.

Browse to the item, select it, and via the small arrow next to the "Add" button, select "Add as link".

Comment: does the class where this code is executed also need to be added to my test project?

Comment: You would usually add a project reference (in whichever project `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` is) to the unit test project.